# Facial Segmentation In android

Tags: android, eclipse, image, image-processing

Folks,
Am making an android application in which ill have to separate the face from the hair and the environmental surroundings. I did some research. Using the circular cropping would not be that efficient because it would not be an efficient face off from the picture as i would loosing some details. i would wishing if i can accomplish this in android? is there any source code already made for this purpose? or any open source library that provides this functionality? i was thinking may be i have to do it through image segmentation if i need it accurately done?? even then am not sure how android treats image segmentation. wouldnt it be a very calculation intensive?? i would appreciate if you people discuss the possibilities with their trade offs. All i want to do is extract the face out of a picture so that i can play with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are existing libraries that will handle this sort of thing for you, namely openCV (please see references).

In short, there are several different ways to do face detection. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. I used principal component analysis (ie: eigenvector decomposition) in the past to find the center of a face, and the alignment of it (ie: is the person leaning to the left or right when facing the camera) so the face could be extracted and normalize along the x-y plane. This method is considered relatively efficient, and requires `O(n^2)` time to calculate (where `n` is the number of pixels in the image), so don't expect these methods to go easy on the CPU.

Other more complicated methods may be used if you want to determine the position of the eyes, determine whether or not the person is smiling, etc.

Below is a fully working example of exactly what you requested using a fairly common image processing library for use in `C`. Good luck!

---

**EDIT:**
Please refer to reference [2] for an example in Java using javaCV.

**References:**

---

1. http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection
2. http://tkgospodinov.com/computer-vision-face-detection-in-java-with-opencv-using-javacv/

Comment: Thank You so much sir for your detailed answer! so there is no already existing example for this in java or android??

Comment: Please see the "edit" to my post above. It looks like there is. Going from C to Java isn't horribly difficult though.

Comment: Thank you for calling me sir... without appending "please stop making a scene".